# Java - Writing to XML file indents everything except the first element

Tags: java, xml, swing

Using JAVA, I am trying, after having opened a .xml file, to append the creation of a new node using a SWING Application. Every new node gets entered correctly EXCEPT the first element which always get stuck at the far left of the file, with no identation.

**schedule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<Schedule>
        <Lesson>
                <Title>Artificial Intelligence</Title>
                <Lecture>
                    <Day>Thursday</Day>
                </Lecture>
                <Professor>John Doe</Professor>
        </Lesson>
        <Lesson>
                <Title>Constraint Satisfaction Problems</Title>
                <Lecture>
                    <Day>Monday</Day>
                </Lecture>
        </Lesson>
</Schedule>
```

My attempt to write to the file :

```
try {
                    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document document = documentBuilder.parse("schedule.xml");
                    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
                        Element newLesson = document.createElement("Lesson");

                        Element newTitle = document.createElement("Title");
                        newTitle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("myLesson"));
                        newLesson.appendChild(newTitle);

                        Element newLecture = document.createElement("Lecture");
                        newLesson.appendChild(newLecture);

                        Element newDay = document.createElement("Day");
                        newDay.appendChild(document.createTextNode("myDay"));
                        newLecture.appendChild(newDay);

                        Element newProfessor = document.createElement("Professor");
                        newProfessor.appendChild(document.createTextNode("myProfessor"));
                        newLesson.appendChild(newProfessor);

                        root.appendChild(newLesson);
                     DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
                     TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                     Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                     StreamResult result = new StreamResult("schedule.xml");
                     transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                     transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "8");
                     transformer.transform(source, result);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Schedule>
        <Lesson>
                <Title>Artificial Intelligence</Title>
                <Lecture>
                    <Day>Thursday</Day>
                </Lecture>
                <Professor>John Doe</Professor>
        </Lesson>
        <Lesson>
                <Title>Constraint Satisfaction Problems</Title>
                <Lecture>
                    <Day>Monday</Day>
                </Lecture>
        </Lesson>
<Lesson>
            <Title>myLesson</Title>
            <Lecture>
                    <Day>myDay</Day>
            </Lecture>
            <Professor>myProfessor</Professor>
    </Lesson>
</Schedule>
```

Comment: It really prints `<Lesson>` at indent 0 and `</Lesson>` at indent 4? Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Because there was a bug: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6296446

Comment: java version: 1.8.0_25

Comment: Could you try `new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "utf-8"));`?

Comment: With this change, we have 0 identation. Every node is in the same row (for the new entry always)

Comment: And, I rewrited the .xml file to make sure there was no hidden tab or whitespace I forgot. Tested with a 100% correct .xml file and I still have the issue, so I doubt it is some forgotten whitespace on the xml file

Comment: This appears to be fixed in Java 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: used a function for space trimming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413413/java-documentbuilder-wrong-indentation-in-xml-file)

**Function:**

```
private static void removeEmptyText(Node node){
    Node child = node.getFirstChild();
    while(child!=null){
        Node sibling = child.getNextSibling();
        if(child.getNodeType()==Node.TEXT_NODE){
            if(child.getTextContent().trim().isEmpty())
                node.removeChild(child);
        }else
            removeEmptyText(child);
        child = sibling;
    }
}
```